# FadeIn and FadeOut with class change in between

Tags: jquery

I want to make an effect which makes whole body disappear then reappear with different font. The problem is that it changes the font during the disappearance, not in time between fadeIn & fadeOut.

Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/F53hG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#switch_font").click(
        function(){
            $("body").fadeOut(550, function(){
                $("body").toggleClass("messed_up_website").fadeIn(550);             
            });    
        });
    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle your class in the callback for fadeOut, rather than chaining all the events together.  Something like this:  (untested, feel free to tweak)

```
$("body")
    .fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $('body').toggleClass('messed_up_website')
            .delay(550).fadeIn('slow);
    });
```

Comment: $('body').toggleClass('messed_up_website')
 -> hahahahaha

Comment: I thought that .delay method does the job, as it turned out, it doesn't. Thank you!

Comment: @metrampaz, the `.delay` method is for the animation queue, which `.toggleClass` doesn't use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the `fadeOut` animation to finish before you can toggle your class. Something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#switch_font").click(

    function() {
        $("body").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).delay(530).toggleClass("messed_up_website").delay(530).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/derekaug/ssZgg/1/